# Browser crashed on youtube-frontend site (invidio.us)

Tags: epiphany, crash

I tried to open (this video)[https://invidio.us/watch?v=BnzYqOn3VkY] on invidio.us and the browser dissapeared.
I wondered how to find a log of the event and all I could think of was tailing dmegs. This is what i found:

`[ 2931.039224] pool[6546]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f52fd54fec7 sp 00007f5230df2ab0 error 4 in libephymain.so[7f52fd50c000+9b000]`

Is this a HTML5 issue?

Using current epiphany (Gnome Web 3.281)

Comment: On second thought: This should have been filed here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementary

Comment: elementary doesn't use launchpad for some time, this should go either to their [github/os-patches](https://github.com/elementary/os-patches/issues) repo or to epiphany's [gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/issues) repo (they have elementaryOS tag there).

Answer (score 0):

Epiphany is crashing. To fix the crash, you will need to report a bug to the developers. And to report a bug to the developers, you will need to gather a stack trace of the crash. [See this page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Community/GettingInTouch/Bugzilla/GettingTraces) for hints on how to get a stack trace of the crash.

If you are able to acquire a quality stack trace and create a bug report, then point me at it and I will take a look. Without a stack trace, it's not possible to debug.